# Selecting ellipses based on mouse coordinates and obtaining seat id from div

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, this, mouse-coordinates

I'm creating a `canvas` based Select Your Own Seat booking system and having difficulty working out how to determine whether one of the circles have been clicked on.
The seats are **dynamically drawn based on pulling** from an array filled with XML data returned from the `CRM system`. I had tried to use the 'this' keyword with the thought that this would help. I thought I could use the coordinates in order to determine which seat was selected then return the ID of that seat in order to request the reservation through the CRM.

Should I create a multi-dimensional array and populate this with the coordinates and the seat ID?

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',domloaded,false);
    function domloaded(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var allseats = document.getElementsByClassName("seat");
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(allseats); 

        for (var j=0; j<arr.length; j++)
       {
    //Get seat status
    var status = arr[j].getAttribute("data-seat-status");
    //Get row position
    var top = arr[j].getAttribute("data-top");
    //Get column position
    var left = arr[j].getAttribute("data-left");
    //Get seat id
    var id = arr[j].getAttribute("id");

    var sAngle = 0;
    var eAngle = 2*Math.PI;

    //Create more space between seats
    left=(left*10);
    top=(top*10);

     var seat = function(){
     function seat(x, y) {
        this.color = "white";
        this.x = left;
        this.y = top;
        this.radius = 4;
    }
        seat.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
    };
        return seat;
    }();
    var drawSeats=new seat(top,left);
    drawSeats.draw(ctx);    

    }
    canvas.onmousedown=function findseats(arr){


  var xleft=arr.clientX;
  var ytop=arr.clientY;
  alert("X coords: " + xleft + ", Y coords: " + ytop);
    for (s=0; s<arr.length; s++){
        if((xleft||((arr[s].getAttribute("data-left")*10)&&(ytop||arr[s].getAttribute("data-top")*10)))){
            alert(arr[s].getAttribute("data-id"));
        }

    }
    }}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/caspianturner/5sycT

Comment: Provide your http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/64yJs/
Thanks - I've not used jsfiddle before, just trying to set it up so it works - currently it's not drawing the seats out in jsfiddle

Comment: Insert Your HTML in `Jsfiddle`,I have your Code but Want to see your HTML and CSS part..

Comment: Sorry - should be on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/caspianturner/5sycT/

Comment: Now you want to click on particular `Red Dot` ?

Comment: Exactly - I want to be able to tell which dot is being clicked on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/AN4Jf/

**You can listen for mousedown events and call handleMouseDown() when the event occurs:**

```
canvas.onmousedown=handleMouseDown;
```

**The mousedown handler gets the mouse position like this:**

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var offsetX=canvas.offsetLeft;
var offsetY=canvas.offsetTop;

function handleMouseDown(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);

    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);


}
```

**Assume your Seat "class" looks something like this:**

```
// Seat "class"
function Seat(x,y,radius,id,seatNo,color){
    this.x=x-200;  // -200 pulls the seats leftward for better display
    this.y=y;
    this.radius=radius;
    this.id=id;
    this.seatNo=seatNo;
    this.color=color
}
```

**Then you can test if the mousedown occurred in any Seat object like this:**

```
Seat.prototype.isMouseInside=function(mouseX,mouseY){
    var dx=mouseX-this.x;
    var dy=mouseY-this.y;
    return(dx*dx+dy*dy<=this.radius*this.radius);
}
```